# why it use void** here?

Tags: c++, v8, reinterpret-cast

the code pick up from [v8-0.2.5](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/0.2.5/include/v8.h#L220)

```
/**
 * Checks whether two handles are the same.
 * Returns true if both are empty, or if the objects
 * to which they refer are identical.
 * The handles' references are not checked.
 */
template <class S> bool operator==(Handle<S> that) {
  void** a = reinterpret_cast<void**>(**this);
  void** b = reinterpret_cast<void**>(*that);
  if (a == 0) return b == 0;
  if (b == 0) return false;
  return *a == *b;
}
```

`Handle` Overload operator* so that `**this` and `*that` return type `T*`.

So it seems

```
  void* a = reinterpret_cast<void*>(**this);
  void* b = reinterpret_cast<void*>(*that);
  return a == b;
```

will also work well?

Comment: This type of magic used to have been done in old C code to pass by reference variables of type void*.

I think if you change the return to a == b and have b as well as a be of type void* it's going to work well.

Comment: If dereferencing a `Handle<T>` yields a `T*`, then this code is deeply flawed, as the comparison generates both false positives and false negatives: If `sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*)` you get false negatives because stuff that does not belong to the objects is included in the comparison, and if `sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*)` you get false positives because only the first four/eight bytes of the objects get compared.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` and `b` had type `void*`, then you couldn't dereference them (without casting them to something else first), so `*a == *b` wouldn't work.

Comment: but couldn't you just a == b?

Comment: No you couldn't because in doc comment it says `objects are identical`, which means they don't have to be THE SAME object for it to return true, 2 distinct object can still compare equal as long as they are identical.

Answer (score 2):

First, I admid that I only read the code in the link diagonally. Apparently, the Handle class overloads the dereferencing operator (`*`) to return the `T*` that is being handled. Thus, the expressions in the first line mean the following:

- `this` is a (possibly cv-qualified) `Handle<T> * const`.
- `*this` is `Handle<T> &`
- `**this` is the return value of the handle's `operator*`, which is the `T*` you mentioned.
- Finally, that `T*` is reinterpreted into a `void**`. Note that one extra indirection is added, so dereferencing the result is possible and will yield a `void* &` instead of a `T&`
- The equivalent line with `that` yields a `S*` that is reinterpreted as a `void**`.

Thus, you get a couple of pointers to different types `T*` and `S*` that are magically reinterpreted as `void**`. Then the code performs null checks and *then*, the magic line:

```
return *a == *b;
```

Which is comparing the (possibly unaligned!) *first `sizeof(void*)` bytes* of the objects of types `T` and `S` that are *actually* pointed to by `a` and `b`. Unless you can be completely sure that `T` and `S` have the proper size and alignment, the check is completely bogus. *For example*, the check would make sense if you know that `T` itself is always a pointer or smart pointer object with the same size of a pointer, so you may have different handles point to different pointer objects that nevertheless point (in the 2nd indirection level) to the same object. This allows the GC to move the underlying object without having to update all handles to it, by simply updating the contents of the 1st level pointers.

```
Handle<T> has T* -----> T = U* pinned in memory -----> actual object U can be moved
```

So, to answer your question, casting only to `void*` (without increasing the indirection) **is not the same** as making the check in the code - your version would compare the pointers, so in my example, two different handles to the same object might compare unequal with your alternate code.

PS: it is also bad style to have your class return `T*` from both `operator*` and `operator->`, because then you are breaking the general identity between `p->x` and `(*p).x`. The de-referencing operator should generally return a `T&` if the member access operator returns a `T*`.

Comment: After looking at the V8 code this is afaics a correct analysis. In my opinion the code as presented has --depending on the types handled -- undefined behavior because arbitrary type objects are accessed as pointers (the reason this is undefined is that some architectures may trap when invalid bit patterns are loaded in their address registers). The proper way would be to cast both `T*` values to `void *` and then compare them numerically; then the bytes of the `T` and the `S` can be compared after casting both `T*` to char pointers, which is the one allowed exception.

Comment: The bytewise comparison is possible because `sizeof(T)` and `sizeof(S)` are known for templates (but ignored in the examples; in fact, if the underlying types are smaller than an address (potentially 8 bytes!), the comparison as it stands compares parts of unrelated memory and is also logically wrong).

Answer (score 0):

[Javier Martín](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537632/7376565) is right. You can't just compare pointers as you sugested in question. First of all in context ov v8 the `Handle<T>` has a restriction on type `T`. You can't take any class and apply Handle to it. `T` is just a facade class that the user deal with: `v8::String`, `v8::Integer` and so on. The object of such types is never created but such classes are used as interfaces to internals.

In reality the pointer that `Handle<>` stores is a pointer to tomething let say "Tag". We have the same object that two `Handle<>` refer if their tags are the same. Internally tag has size of `void*` and somehow refers to the real object. The user doesn't need to know what Tag is so `Handle<>` uses `void*` instead. Some thoughts

1. `Handle<T>` has `T*` --> Tag (not `T`) --(somehow)--> real object (not of type T)
2. Tag has size of `void*`. And user does not need to know about real type of Tag.
3. Two tags are equal - they refer to the same object.
4. (summary, from the user sight of view) `Handle<T>` has `void**` --> `void*`

So the original `bool operator==(Handle<S> that)` is doing what is supposed to do: compare values of tags. But check pointers at first.